# How do I get Html.RouteLink() to work with a RouteValueDictionary while passing Html Attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Hey there SO... here's a riddle:

```
    <%: Html.RouteLink("asd",item.RouteValues) %>
    <%: Html.RouteLink("asd",item.RouteValues, new{title="title"}) %>
```

The first line correctly spits out this code:

```
    <a href="/">asd</a>
```

The second line incorrectly spits out this code:

```
    <a href="/?Count=4&amp;Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&amp;Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D" title="title">asd</a>
```

I was expecting the code to look like this:

```
<a href="/" title="title">asd</a>
```

So I tried to be a bit more explicit in the view by writing it this way:

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("asd",(RouteValueDictionary)item.RouteValues, new{title="title"}) %>
```

But I had the same (incorrect) result.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As I'm looking at the overloads I'm realizing there's a difference between `object routValues` and `RouteValueDictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there was no overload for `Html.RouteLink(string, RouteValueDictionary, object)`

So I needed to pass my html attriute as a dictionary like this:

```
    <%: Html.RouteLink(
        "link",
        item.RouteValues, 
        new Dictionary<string,object>{{"title", "title text"}}) %>
```

Kind of messy... but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in the RouteValueDictionary when an anonymous object is expected.